# Random youtube embed, firefox issues

Tags: php, html, youtube

I'm trying to just do a simple random video on a youtube embed like so:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/<? echo $videos[array_rand($videos)]; ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Which works fine in Chrome, but in Firefox it appears to cache the embed so I get the same video every time. But when I clear the cache I still get the same video... There are no cookies being set either.

Answer (score 0):

Well it appears to be only when you refresh via right click or F5. If you do it via the address bar then it loads another video.